# Calling printf() after scanf() returns nothing

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to learn C and I've started by building a simple change calculator.  At the moment, I'm just trying to take the user input `8.68` and output it, output the loonies and output the quarters. However, the last 3 `printf()` calls return nothing:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    double value = 0;
    int loonies = value;
    double remainder = value - loonies;


    printf("Please enter the amount to be paid: $");
    scanf("%lf", value);

    printf("%lf", value);
    printf("%d", loonies);
    printf("%lf", remainder);
}
```

This is the output.  The prompt asks for the user input and then the program ends:

```
Please enter the amount to be paid: $8.68

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Comment: Your `scanf` is wrong. Should be `&value`.

Comment: You need `scanf("%lf", &value);`, pass it a pointer to the variable, so that it can write to it.

Comment: Note that `double remainder = value - loonies;` does *not* define a formula. It *does* perform a one-time calculation. And that calculation is `0 - 0 = 0` since you've initialized both `value` and `loonies` to 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing an '&'. Scanf requires you to pass *pointers* to the variables you want to read into.

```cpp
scanf("%lf", &value);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'll accept your answer.

Comment: But the same issue remains.  Now this is my output `Please enter the amount to be paid: $8.68
8.68000000.000000
Process finished with exit code 0`.  The remaining 2 `printf()` calls are not invoked.

Comment: @OnurOzbek You need a `\n` at the end of each `printf` format string, e.g. `printf("%lf\n", value);` The `\n` is a newline character. Without it, all of the printed text is on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `&` in your `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf` expects the address of the variable that you are passing. Here in your case you have to give `&value`.

The full code I am pasting here

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  double value = 0;
  int loonies = value;
  double remainder = value - loonies;

  printf("Please enter the amount to be paid: $");
  scanf("%lf", &value);

  printf("Values- %0.2lf\n", value); //'\n' and 'Values-' added 
  printf("Loonies - %d\n", loonies); //'\n' and 'Loonies-' added
  printf("remainder - %0.2lf\n", remainder); //'\n' and 'remainder-' added
}
```

Output I am getting is

```
Please enter the amount to be paid: $8.68                             
Values- 8.68                                                          
Loonies - 0                                                           
remainder - 0.00
```

Edit: Here I am giving `%0.2lf` for printing only two decimal characters